# Error when trying to run Cocos2d-JS project on Android

Tags: android, ant, cocos2d-js

The error I get is in this part:

```
running: '"C:\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin\ant" clean debug -f C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\N
ormero\Games\Aztec\frameworks\runtime-src\proj.android\build.xml -Dsdk.dir="C:\a
ndroid-sdk"'

The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
Error running command, return code: 1
```

I'm running:

```
cocos run -p android
```

On windows 7 64bit. I have googled but I'm stumped. Also I'm not a genius in Java nor Android, hence I use Cocos JS.

EDIT: Someone pointed out to me that the dot (.) in proj.android might be causing the issue. Any way I can fix this easily?

EDIT2: It happens during the compile, but the weird thing is, I can execute the command it says it errors on, and then it goes BUILD SUCCESFUL.

Comment: I'd like to be able to give you a real answer, but all I can do is point you to the [cocos2d forums](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org), you are more likely to find answers to this kind of problems there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've searched accross google and that forum, but none of the "solutions" work for me unfortunately. As I said I can run the erroring command succesfully and build the .apk file. I can then install it on my phone with adb, so it's something.

Then it unfortunately doesn't work on my phone (does work on an emulator) but that's a different issue I guess!

Comment: Oh nope. The tests also wont run. Same problem(s)

Comment: Yeah, I meant maybe posting your problem there, if  none of the existing threads are helpful. Anyway, it's really strange.. It could be the "-" in the path, or maybe it's too long? I'm just guessing here.

Comment: Yeah thx for the guesses haha. I posted my question there but not responses yet.

Tried removing all the "-" before, but no cigar

Answer (score 1):

Your python version is not suitable. reinstall python 2.7.5
and it will be work =)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the exact same issue then searched and found that "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect" error message is probably related to Python.

[The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23623947/the-filename-directory-name-or-volume-label-syntax-is-incorrect)

I have both Python 2 and 3 in my machine but my PATH is pointing to 2.7.0 due to failsafe setup for some node.js projects. Then I reviewed the release note of Python 2.7 below:

https://hg.python.org/cpython/raw-file/v2.7.12/Misc/NEWS

And found there are numerous issues are associated with path. Without touching cocos2d first, I decided to remove 2.7.0 and installed 2.7.8. (just an old binary)

The propblem was solved immediately.

(Thanks justderb to remind and more details are provided.)

Comment: Can you edit the answer to link to this "documenation python 2.7.0 is having path issue"?